# How to stop javascript counter at specific number using iMacros and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, counter, imacros, mutation-observers

I have 2 challenges. I'd like to stop the counter on this [demo page, see example 4](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Multifunctional-jQuery-Countdown-Stopwatch-Plugin-Timer-js/) when it reaches 50, using plain javascript and also using iMacros with javascript.

Here's the javascript that I'm using.

```js
var start_button = document.getElementById('AutomatoOrphanInput_INPUT_6_tag_DIV_7_tag_DIV_4_tag_BODY_0_tag_HTML_0');
var stop_button = document.getElementById('AutomatoOrphanInput_INPUT_8_tag_DIV_7_tag_DIV_4_tag_BODY_0_tag_HTML_0');

//start_button.click()

var timerId = setInterval(function() {
    console.time('session_duration');
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter')[0].innerHTML;

    if (counter => 50) {
        stop_button.click();
        clearInterval(timerId);
    }
    console.timeEnd('session_duration');
}, 200);
```

In console I get "Uncaught TypeError innerhtml. Cannot read property "innerHTML" undefined"
What am I doing wrong here?

And then how do I get this stop function to work in iMacros?

I heard that using JS MutationObserver would be a better solution instead of the infinite loop. How would I use that?

Comment: The `getElementById()` function returns either a **single** element, or `null` if the "id" cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

Pfff, always mention your FCI (Full Config Info) when you open a Thread, many Commands are not implemented (or get broken!) for all Browsers/Versions...
=> iMacros for FF v9.0.3/v8.9.7...?, FF51...?, OS...?

But anyway, here is one easy Solution in 3 Lines in pure '.iim' (I don't do '.js' Scripts), which will work for all Browsers, and that you can easily convert to JavaScript if you wish...
It simply uses '!TIMEOUT_STEP' (+ Relative Positioning for extra Reliability, not even necessary):

```
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 100
TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=TXT:timer<SP>has<SP>been<SP>executed<SP>50<SP>times.
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON ATTR=VALUE:"timer.stop()"
```

Full Script demonstrating on your Site, shortened to 10sec (instead of 50) + Vertical Scrolling Adjustment for visual following (broken in v9.0.3 => '!ERRORIGNORE' added to make the Script v9.0.3 compliant):

```
VERSION BUILD=8820413 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
URL GOTO=http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Multifunctional-jQuery-Countdown-Stopwatch-Plugin-Timer-js/

URL GOTO=javascript:window.scrollBy(0,680)
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 100
TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=TXT:timer<SP>has<SP>been<SP>executed<SP>10<SP>times.
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON ATTR=VALUE:"timer.stop()"
URL GOTO=javascript:window.scrollBy(0,-190)
```

(You may need to adjust the Scroll Values for your Screen/Resolution/etc...)
(Tested on iMacros for FF v8.8.2, PM v26.3.3 (=FF47), Win10-x64.)

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, but I'm looking for a js within iMacros solution.

Comment: Yeah well, a Solution in 3 Lines in pure '.iim' (instead of the cumbersome original '.js Script) will work in all 4 Browsers and can always be converted to a '.js' Script...! (... which will only work in FF until iMacros for FF v9.0.3...)